# How do I find a PROM chip for a Roland D20?

Tags: synthesizer, keyboard, electronics, replacement-parts

I'm looking for the `u16` prom chip for CPU board of a Roland D20,
would anybody have any idea where i can get one?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about repair work rather than audio/visual production.

Comment: @AJHenderson I think it's on-topic, as it's basically about maintaining audio gear, and an appropriate answer is an explanation rather than a shopping-style link.

Comment: @WarriorBob - I suppose it's debateable, but it's also a musical instrument, not Audio/Visual gear.  Would someone asking about fixing the neck of their acoustic guitar be on topic?

Comment: @AJHenderson That's actually a good point. I tend to categorize synthesizers in my head as "production equipment" more than "instruments", probably because they often look like electronic boxes, but you're right that it's not clear where that line is. Good call [putting this on meta](http://meta.avp.stackexchange.com/questions/331/where-is-the-dividing-line-on-repair-questions?noredirect=1).

Answer (score 4):

Try contacting Roland or your official Roland Service Center first. Korg and Yamaha both have reputations for helping out with their products even when they are long out of warranty. Roland doesn't have that reputation as much, but you should still start by asking them.

If you can't get Roland to supply you with a chip, then look for forums where people who maintain old Roland gear hang out. It seems unlikely that anyone would stock ROM chips like this, so you are looking for someone who (a) has a D20 already, (b) knows how to pull and read the PROM chip and (c) has a new blank chip to burn the data to.

Finally, if you can't find a friendly helper in a forum, check eBay and similar. Again, you are unlikely to find someone who offers exactly what you want. Your best bet will be to find someone who deals in old synth ROMs and PROMs or someone who deals in old Roland parts, Ideally both.

Comment: Sorry about the off topic, My first post,lol ,I Tried e-bay and googled everything, but i will try Roland then, thanks for the help,

Comment: You need to contact Roland, as any off-the-shelf PROM will not have the encoded data that Roland has provided for the this chip, remember a PROM contains data.

Comment: An off-the-shelf PROM isn't enough - you also need a working PROM to copy. I've done this before to bring an old Sun workstation back to life - the same process should be possible for a synth.

Comment: Thanks for all the help and info, I think Roland is the only ones who will have this then, Just my luck,lol, thanks once agian James